# Django; Tips for making views thin

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm a beginner and I have been  working on project using Django.
I am wondering if there's a good way to avoid repeating the same code.
Also if there are similar logic in some functions, how can I decide if the logic is organized or not.

for example,

```
def entry_list(request):
    entry_list = Entry.objects.all()

    #this part is repeated
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)


    paginator = Paginator(entry_list, 10)

    try:
        entries = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        entries = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        entries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'blog/entry_list.html', {'entries': entries})
```

The logic to paginate is repeated in some other functions as well.

Where should I put the repeated code and how can I decide if I should organize code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using *function-based* views

You could *encapsulate* it in another function (for example construct such function in a file named `utils.py`):

```
# in app/utils.py

def get_page_entries(entry_list, page, per_page=10):
    paginator = Paginator(entry_list, per_page)
    try:
        return paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        return paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        return paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

You can then use it like:

```
# app/views.py

from app.utils import get_page_entries

def entry_list(request):
    entry_list = Entry.objects.all()

    entries= get_page_entries(entry_list, request.GET.get('page', 1))

    return render(request, 'blog/entry_list.html', {'entries': entries})
```

You can provide an optional third parameter with the number of elements per page. If not provided, it will by default be 10.

Or we can encapsulate the `request.GET.get(..)` logic as well, like:

```
# in app/utils.py

def get_page_entries(entry_list, querydict, per_page=10, key='page', default_page=1):
    page = querydict.get(key, default_page)
    paginator = Paginator(entry_list, per_page)
    try:
        return paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        return paginator.page(default_page)
    except EmptyPage:
        return paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

and thus call it with:

```
# app/views.py

from app.utils import get_page_entries

def entry_list(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/entry_list.html', {
        'entries': get_page_entries(Entry.objects.all(), request.GET)
    })
```

## Using *class-based* views

You however do *not* need to use function-based views. This use case is covered by the [**`ListView`** class [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview):

```
class EntryListView(ListView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'blog/entry_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'entries'
    paginate_by = 10
```

and then in the `urls.py`, use `EntryListView.as_view()` instead of the function, so:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from app.views import EntryListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('entries', EntryListView.as_view(), name='entry-list'),
]
```

Note only did we reduce the number of lines of code, this is also a more *declarative* way of developing: instead of specifying *how* we want to do something, we specify *what* we want to do. How it is done is more up to Django's implementation of a `ListView`. Furthermore by providing the settings as attributes of the class, we can easily develop more tooling that take these parameters into account.

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same questions for several things including:

- **functions** I might use many times in my views,
- **messages** I would use many times in my views but also tests (in order to test behavior of my apps),
- **exceptions** that could be used in many models or views,
- **choices** when defining Charfields which value can be only specific values,
- **context** values that could be used in many templates,
- etc.

Here how I work for instance:

- **functions**: a `utils.py` file as Willem said does the trick,
- **messages**: I've got a `customMessages.py` file used for that, where I define simple messages (e.g.:`SUCCESS_M_CREATE_OBJECT=_("You created this object successfully.")`, then used by calling `customMessages.SUCCESS_M_CREATE_OBJECT` in my models, tests or views) or more complexe ones with variable fields for instance, defined by a function and called with `lambda` in my tests,
- **context**: by defining dedicated functions in my `context_processors.py` returning dictionaries of context vars, registering them in my `settings.py` and then I'm fine if want to call any in my templates,
- etc.

Well, there is always a way to not repeat yourself for anything you do in Python and Django, and you are just right to ask yourself those questions at anytime in your development, because your futur self will thank you for that!